# VS Code: pass environment variables to build task

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I pass environment variables to my build task? According to what I've found at many places, this can be specified in the `tasks.json`. However, I tried without success:

`tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "options": {
        "env": {
            "CXX": "/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++",
            "LDFLAGS": "-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/c++ -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/c++ -L/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib",
            "CXXFLAGS": "-I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include"
        },
        "shell": {"executable": "/bin/zsh"}
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "make test",
            "command": "gmake",
            "args": [
                "-f",
                "Test.Makefile"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Test.Makefile`:

```
$(info $(LDFLAGS))
$(info $(CXXFLAGS))
```

When I launch this task, the makefile prints no values for the variables. In my usual terminal (where I have exported these variables in my `.zshrc`) the variables are seen by `gmake`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use [Environment variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables)

Comment: @rioV8 I think you misunderstood me, I don’t want to pass the value of an environment variable as command line argument, but export it to the build command’s environment. Basically, what an *export* in the shell would do.

Comment: does it work if you add the `options` part to the task, not as global options

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough just to do this, for example to set the pyenv version, use an env set as the "command", and the rest as args:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Run Pytest (Python 3.6)",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "PYENV_VERSION=3.6",
      "args": [
        "python3.6",
        "-m",
        "pytest"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And it can get a bit obnoxious, but you can even chain commands together, e.g.:

```
...
"command": "PYENV_VERSION=3.6",
"args": [
  "python3.6",
  "-m",
  "pip",
  "install",
  "--upgrade",
  "pip",
  "&&",
  "PYENV_VERSION=3.6",
  "python3.6",
  "-m",
  "pip",
  "install",
  "-r",
  "requirements-dev.txt",
  "&&",
  "PYENV_VERSION=3.6",
  "python3.6",
  "-m",
  "pytest"
],
...
```